# Not able to use a variable in query for mysql fetch using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a working code which save the mysql fetched rows to a csv file based on Id. But when I use the id as variable for query, file created is empty. After referring  the sites i tried to change the query by including single  and double quotes, but still it doesn't work. Anyone please help me. Sorry if there is a simple mistake which i could not understand.

Note: $id is printing the id
      Its also working when used a sample id instead of $id

```
for ($i=0;$i<=0;$i++)
{
$id=$locus[$i];
$dbo = new PDO($dbc, $user, $pass);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM anatomy WHERE locus_id='$id'";

$qry = $dbo->prepare($sql);
$qry->execute();
$data = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

while ($row = $qry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
     {
      fputcsv($data, $row);
     }
}

chmod("file.csv",0777);

?>
```

Comment: you can try use it, `"SELECT * FROM anatomy WHERE locus_id = '{$id}'";`

Comment: That also results in empty file @LLL

Comment: Can you print the `$sql` string command result? And I think you can remove out PDO object from for loop.

Comment: Is there value in $id !

Comment: yes value is there in $id (i checked it) @deemi.  $sql prints SELECT * FROM anatomy WHERE ='LOC_Os02g40070 ' (hhowever i notice a space between id and last single quote -LLL..but dont know the problem..

Comment: If you use `$dbo->query()` instead of `$dbo->prepare()` ? Because I search php doc the prepare should use with. ref bind.http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: If you want use `prepare()`, I think you can try this code `$sql = "SELECT * FROM anatomy WHERE locus_id = :id";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
$sth->execute(array(':id' => $id));
$red = $sth->fetchAll();`

Comment: Sorry for consuming your valuable time.But still file is created as empty.@LLL I used `$id=$locus[$i];$dbo = new PDO($dbc, $user, $pass);`before the code you provided and `fputcsv($data, $red);`  at the end (all together inside loop). I  hope i didnt made any mistake

Answer (score 0):

The issue, it seems, is that the $id is being taken as a literal. You may wish to concatenate the id such as:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM anatomy WHERE locus_id='".$id."'";
```

Note that you may need to play around with the quotations.

Comment: I tried all the way by changing quotes of your suggested query. But the file is still empty@Future

Comment: So you tried:
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM anatomy WHERE locus_id=".$id; ?

Answer (score 0):

Now I solved the issue. It was the problem with the white space. So used trim() to remove it.

Two changes i made was added the following line to remove whitespace
    $id=trim($id);
Second change was moved the file open command outside the for loop